# What tags are available in RestTemplate-instrumented spans using Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: resttemplate, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I'm including Spring Cloud Sleuth + Zipkin 2.2.7 in my Spring Boot application, and am using injected RestTemplates so that calls to them are instrumented and sent to zipkin.

My zipkin spans arising from RestTemplate calls contain tags for `http.method` and `http.path`, but no other HTTP info.

Is there any way to surface *query parameters* in tags? Sometimes there is interesting information in them that would be really useful to surface in a tag (e.g. `GET /foo?includeSuperSensitiveData=true`).

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain what is going on under the hood:

[`TraceRestTemplateBeanPostProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/4c2eb7fb7227eafa7545a60307cd0811dc8dda86/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/client/TraceWebClientAutoConfiguration.java#L284-L296) modifies all the `RestTemplate` beans. As you can see there, it injects a [`LazyTracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/2.2.x/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/client/TraceWebClientAutoConfiguration.java#L323-L329) that is using a [`brave.spring.web.TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor`](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/instrumentation/spring-web/src/main/java/brave/spring/web/TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java) to instrument the http calls. So this is done by Brave, not Sleuth.

You might be able to extend `TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor`, add the details you need to your implementation and create a bean (you might need to disable the config class that creates it if there is no `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`).